# python pandas data comparing

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to compare two excels, one is the user matrix, the other one is I generated from a host. I want to know if the user settings are correct as of the matrix.

the results I got the from the host, I imported to pandas: the user groups here is as column names!

```
    Name Users  Domain Admins     Administrators   Schema Admins 
0   xxx   NaN             Yes                Yes             NaN
```

the problem is :

the excel matrix is like

```
user:         groups
xxx           administrators
              schema admins
              domain admins
```

here is what I have tried:

I will replace all the Yes with the columns name:

```
for i in df.columns:
df[i].replace('Yes',i,inplace=True)
```

remove the null from it.

```
group=df.dropna(axis='columns',how='all')
```

now it's like this:

```
  Name Users  Domain  Admins     Administrators  Schema Admins 

   0     xxx   Domain admins    Administrators  Schema Admins
```

the other one like:

```
User Account Name    Group
0    xxx             Domain Admins, Local admin,Administrators
```

I don't know what to do next. please guide me how to compare the index values in a loop for all the indexs.

the original two excel like this:

```
user:         groups
xxx           administrators
              schema admins
              domain admins

yyy           administrators
              domain admins

zzz           administrators
              schema admins
```

the other file like:

```
username   administrators   schema admins  domain admins
xxx               yes            yes            NaN
yyy               yes            NaN            yes
```

Comment: Your excel matrix , does it have blanks for the user row when it is associated with multiple groups or it is repeated multiple times ?

Comment: No, After I imported the matrix into the pandas , actually the record has \n in between.Domain Admins\nLocal admin\nAdministrators.

Comment: Answer given let me know if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it can be done:

**Step 1:  Transform host df**

```
cols = ['administrators', 'schema admins', 'domain admins']
df1['merged'] = df1[cols].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x[x.notnull()]), axis = 1) ##df1 is host df
```

**Step 2: Transform your matrix df**

```
df.user = df.user.ffill()  ## Fill the empty rows with same user name
grouped_df = df.groupby("user")['groups'].apply(','.join).reset_index() ## merge same user name to 1 row
```

**Step 3: Comparing both df**

```
result_df = pd.merge(df1, grouped_df, how='inner', left_on="merged", right_on="user") ## The left_on/right_on will change according to the column name you have
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, it doesn't work. maybe my question is not clear. let me explain again.
```
user:         groups
xxx           administrators
              schema admins
              domain admins

yyy           administrators
              domain admins

zzz           administrators
              schema admins
```
the other file like:
````
username   administrators   schema admins  domain admins
xxx               yes                     yes                    NaN
yyy               yes                     NaN                   yes

Comment: You need to check the sample df which I created in my answer and what you have..are those look similar or different. If it is different, kindly put a image of how you df look in pandas!1

Comment: it's different, I've updated the question, I put the original excel at the end.

Comment: Changed according to your new excel format..you can upvote the answer if you found useful

Comment: can you run it?

Comment: Ya.. it is running in my system..what error are you getting ?

Comment: Hi Rahul, I managed to sort all the data together , I posted in another one , can you have a look?

Answer (score 1):

I would let the pandas imported from the host (let us call it `df_host`) unchanged, and create columns for groups in the pandas imported from the *matrix* (called `df_matrix`):

```
groups = ['Users', 'Domain Admins', 'Administrators', 'Schema Admins']

for g in groups:
    df_matrix[g] = df_matrix.Group.str.contains(g)
```

Next I would use the user name as index in both dataframes:

```
df_matrix.set_index('Account Name', inplace=True)
df_host.set_index('Name', inplace=True)
```

You can now easily join the dataframes:

```
df_comp = df_matrix.join(df_host, how='outer', lsuffix='_matrix', rsuffix='_host')
```

You finally should have a single dataframe with one row per user, and one column for groups seen from the host and seen from the excel matrix, which should allow easy comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

You can add data to a dictionary to make things easier. If following is data file:

```
user:         groups
xxx           administrators
              schema admins
              domain admins
user:         groups
yyy           administrators
              domain admins
user:         groups
zzz           administrators
              schema admins
```

Following code will create a dictionary:

```
with open('userdata.txt', 'r') as f:
    # read data file and split into lines; also trim lines; 
    datalist = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), f.readlines())) 
    userdict = {}                               # dictionary to collect data; 
    username=""; grplist = []; newuser = True   # variable to read data from file: 
    for line in datalist: 
        if line.startswith('user:'):
            if not(username=="" and len(grplist)==0):   # omit at first run
                userdict[username] = grplist            # put user data into dictionary
                username=""; grplist=[]; newuser=True       # clear variable for new user; 
        elif newuser:
            username, grpname = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), line.split()))
            grplist.append(grpname)     # append group name to temporary list
            newuser = False
        else: 
            grplist.append(line)        # append more groups; 

userdict[username] = grplist
print(userdict)
```

Output:

```
{'yyy': ['administrators', 'domain admins'], 'zzz': ['administrators', 'schema admins'], 'xxx': ['administrators', 'schema admins', 'domain admins']}
```

If data in second file is as follows:

```
  Account Name                               Group
          xxx  administrators , schema admins, domain admins
          yyy  administrators , domain admins
          zzz  administrators , schema admins
```

Following code will get dictionary from it:

```
with open('userdata2.txt', 'r') as f:
    # read data file and split into lines; also trim lines; 
    datalines = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), f.readlines())) 
    userdict2={}
    for line in datalines[1:]:  # omit first line which is only header
        infolist = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), line.split(" ",1)))
        username = infolist[0].strip()
        grplist = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), infolist[1].split(",")))
        userdict2[username] = grplist

print(userdict2)
```

Output:

```
{'zzz': ['administrators', 'schema admins'], 'xxx': ['administrators', 'schema admins', 'domain admins'], 'yyy': ['administrators', 'domain admins']}
```

To compare 2 dictionaries, just use `==`:

```
print(userdict == userdict2)
```

Output:

```
True
```

To compare groups of a particular user:

```
print(userdict['xxx'] == userdict1['xxx'])
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: yes, it's a very good idea to use the dictionary. I think this will be the right way, I've updated the excel at the end.   I want to know if user xxx 's group matches in both excel.

Comment: To compare groups of a particular user, one can use `print(userdict['xxx'] == userdict1['xxx'])`. I have added this in my answer above. You should also upvote/accept answer that is helpful to you.

Comment: hi, the second file is different, please see my update.

Comment: You should accept this answer and post another question with new comparison. Otherwise answers will become very long.